# How I can see all tables of a specific procedure in oracle?

Tags: oracle

example

```
Package    procedure    Table

 pkg1        proc1        tab1 (table used in proc1)
 pkg1        proc1        tab2 (table used in proc1)
 pkg1        proc2        tab3 (table used in proc2)
 pkg1        proc2        tab4 (table used in proc2)
```

Comment: A procedure inside a package? This is almost impossible. While Oracle stores dependencies, it can only tell you which tables are referenced from the package (except even for tables used in dynamic SQL). It cannot tell you which procedure within. You'd have to parse the package code yourself, which would be tough to say the least.

Comment: Thx for the response.

Answer (score 2):

Use this one:

```
SELECT *
FROM USER_DEPENDENCIES
WHERE TYPE IN ('PACKAGE', 'PACKAGE BODY')
    AND REFERENCED_TYPE = 'TABLE';
```

However, of course it does not cover dynamic SQL statements.